# When should data source and delegate be different objects?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, delegates

Under what conditions is it necessary to have separate objects for data source and delegate? Most applications I've come across make a point to have `self.currentView.delegate = self`. Is it solely for readability and sectioning off code?

Comment: It's never necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A data source is simply a kind of delegate with a different name and a different set of responsibilities. Apple [explains this nicely](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11-SW6) in the docs:

> A data source is like a delegate except that, instead of being
>   delegated control of the user interface, it is delegated control of
>   data.

Separating the two roles *allows* developers to specify different objects for each when it suits them rather than forcing them to use a single object for two related but different tasks. It's never *necessary* to use different objects for the two roles, but it can sometimes be convenient.

Consider a view controller containing a table that can switch between several "modes," where each mode displays the same items with different details. One way to implement such a table is to do everything in the view controller, but then you end up with code like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *theCell = nil;
    switch (self.selectedMode) {
        case kFirstMode: {
            // set up the kind of cell required for mode 1
            break;
        }
        case kSecondMode: {
            // set up the kind of cell required for mode 2
            break;
        }
        //...and so on...
    }
    return theCell;
}
```

You can smell the negative code review already, right?

Another, arguably better approach is to create separate data source objects for each mode. When the user switches modes, you just swap in a new data source that knows how to display the data for the selected mode. This scheme works even better when the different modes display completely different data items rather than different aspects of the same items.

Comment: Thanks for the commentary. The question above wasn't exactly what I was after but you answered what I really want to know - I have a table view that toggles between two different lists and was wondering how best to manage that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Pointing to self (as "the view controller") is certainly popular and I believe this is because its just "easier" to write all your code in one place.

If you follow any architecture design patterns, most will want you to create objects with single responsibility. This means your class is responsible for one thing and one thing only.

You can read more about this pattern here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Putting that into practice, you would have a view controller this is responsible only for the layout of your view and an additional data source class that is only responsible for loading data.

Following these design patterns usually means you have neater, more maintainable code with reduced [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

A class that conforms to any type of "Data Source" protocol (delegate) is also reusable. It means you could use the same data logic across multiple view controllers without code duplication.

Comment: Apple has a heavy emphasis on the MVC pattern (which includes data sources and delegates) and that's why their APIs are designed this way. Not because of the "Single Responsibility Principle". (source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html)

Comment: MVC and single responsibility are quite compatible ways of thinking about software. Indeed, half the purpose of MVC is making sure that view layer stuff doesn't take on too much responsibility.

Comment: @theMonster You've twice now linked to the MVC page to justify your reasoning. Maybe you should read it again. It uses the word *delegate* only twice (one of those as a verb), and *data source* exactly once but in a different context.

Comment: @pixelchild I think this would be a stronger answer if you used "the view controller" in place of "self" in the first line. Every object has a `self`, and it's important to be clear about what object you're talking about.

Comment: @Caleb The docs mention it 4 times and I've linked to it 3 times. Also, has more info on the subject in in the side bar. Sounds like you should read it.

Comment: @theMonster don't get so defensive. We are only trying to help educate you. Perhaps you can explain to us in detail how delegates are "tightly" coupled to the MVC pattern. I think the exercise itself will be good for you to discover what your trying to say.

Comment: @pixelchild I've updated my Answer to be a little less convoluted and more to the point. Hopefully, this will **help** you understand how they're tightly integrated.

Comment: @theMonster Two of the "mentions" occur in the sidebar, essentially the table of contents for the entire *Concepts in Objective-C Programming* document. By that logic, delegates are also important in class clusters because *delegate* is "mentioned" twice [on the Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4-SW1) page.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss this with me, then open up a chat and I'll be more than happy to oblige, but as much as I'd like it to be, the commenting system doesn't revolve around @theMonster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not be understanding datasources and delegates.

Your datasource is simply the data your want the item, i.e. UIITableView, UICollectionView, UIPicker, etc to use.

These elements as mentioned above have delegates that you can respond to. Most of the time, the code for the datasource and delegates lives in your implementation file, usually some sort of UIViewController implementation.

You can create another object that handles the delegates of the control, but my opinion is in most cases that just adds another layer that is not needed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: So - in a large project, my data 'model' would be the data source? In the storyboard I just need to create a referencing outlet to my new class?

Comment: Your storyboard is a view controller, you create a class that inherits from UIViewController or UITableViewController. Your custom class acts as the delegate/datasource for your ui elements. Your view controller can get the data from another source (Core Data, REST, text file, etc) It sounds like reading a book could help as well. I recommend Big Nerd Ranch's book on iOS. That will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Delegation**: The responsibilities of the object is delegated to another object. 
Forexample: We used delegation with UITableView, UITextField and UITextView, so that it tells about changes, updates with respect to certain events.

**Data source**: A duty of data source is to provide data to another object when requested.
Forexample: Data source pattern is used with table views and collection views. Telling them numbers of row and cell to be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs:

> A coordinating controller provides services such as:
>
> - **Responding to delegation messages and observing notifications**
> - Responding to action messages
> - Managing the life cycle of owned objects (for example, releasing them at the proper time) ...

However it's important to realize that given the circumstances you can break this pattern. But the ends should justify the means. So when is it necessary? Whenever you as the programmer deem it cleaner than having all the callbacks in one place.

sources: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html), [Wiki - MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)

Comment: I don't believe the MVC pattern has anything to do with delegates. Dont get me wrong i love the MVC pattern but unless I'm mistaken. Delegates are just pointers to objects that conform to a protocol (They are business logic contracts). You can create MVC views very easily without a single delegate.

Comment: @pixelchild If you read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html then you'll see that delegation is very tightly integrated into the MVC pattern and a big reason why it's in the language. I've edited my post to include this link.

Comment: It's far from clear that you're supposed to set a table's data source to a model object. A model generally shouldn't know about specific views, but the only way a model object could reasonably respond to a message like `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is for it to know what data each table is supposed to display.

Comment: @theMonster What's in the language? MVC or delegation? Neither in built into Objective-C. They are both constructs of the libraries, not the language.

Comment: @theMonster I think you are little confused on the difference between "contract programming" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) and the MVC pattern. Which is okay because it can be very confusing. Apple use delegates/protocols heavily in the Cocoa API yes and as they should as its good programming practice. However delegates themselves as i mentioned are just objects that conform to contracts and has nothing to do with the MVC pattern.

Comment: @rmaddy Protocols are built into the language.

Comment: @theMonster Yes, protocols are built into the language. But your 1st comment (the one I was replying to) makes no mention of protocols. Delegation and MVC are both design patterns that can be implemented in many different programming languages. It just so happens that in Objective-C, delegation is typically implemented using protocols. But that does not mean that delegation is in the language.

Comment: @rmaddy As I said to Caleb, open up a chat room and invite me if you'd like to discuss this further.